# How to use "RAISE INFO, RAISE LOG， RAISE DEBUG” to track log in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, debug-print

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mover(src text, dst text, cpquery text, conname text, ifbin boolean) returns void as
$$
        DECLARE
                cnt integer;
                dlcnt integer;
                del_count integer;
                ret text;

        BEGIN
                SELECT  pg_catalog.dblink_copy_open(conname, dst, ifbin) INTO ret ;
                RAISE LOG 'dblink_open %',ret;

                execute 'SELECT  1 as check FROM ' || src ||' limit 1' into cnt;
                IF cnt=0 THEN
                        PERFORM pg_sleep(2);
                END IF;

                IF ifbin=true THEN
                        RAISE DEBUG 'Start to Copy data with binary';
                        execute 'COPY (' || cpquery || '  ) to function pg_catalog.dblink_copy_write with binary';
                        RAISE DEBUG 'Finish Copy data';
                ELSE
                        RAISE DEBUG 'Start to Copy data without binary';
                        execute 'COPY (' || cpquery || '  ) to function pg_catalog.dblink_copy_write';
                        RAISE DEBUG 'Finish Copy data';
                END IF;

                execute 'DELETE FROM ' || src;

                GET DIAGNOSTICS del_count=ROW_COUNT;
                RAISE INFO 'DELETE % rows',del_count;

                SELECT  pg_catalog.dblink_copy_end() INTO ret;
                RAISE LOG 'dblink_end %',ret;
        END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

As code, I want to put some message into log by using `RAISE`, but where is the location
of my log file ? and where `RAISE DEBUG` output?

Answer (score 20):

They can either be output to the *Postgres* log, reported back to the client, or both. These are controlled by server-side settings, `log_min_messages` and `client_min_messages`.

See the following doc for more details:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

As *@a_horse_with_no_name* suggested: These parameters can also be set via the [`SET`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) command from the client.

It can be set via the *SQL*: `set client_min_messages to 'debug';`